# code breaks when trying to access database

Tags: php, html, sql, mailer

When I try to update my database as a check for resetting the password for a user my complete "forgot password" page dies. I really can't see where i went wrong. can someone help me fix this?

```
function mailer($to, $user)
{
$result = "";
$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_?!-0123456789";
$charArray = str_split($chars);
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $randItem = array_rand($charArray);
    $result .= "".$charArray[$randItem];
}
$updateStmt = $db -> prepare('UPDATE Gebruiker SET Code = ? WHERE Gebruikersnaam = ?;');
$updateStmt -> execute(array($result, $user));
$updateStmt-> closeCursor();
```

Error log says the following:

```
[28-Apr-2016 16:56:47 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: loggedin in /home/joeynlxj/public_html/fnb/layout/header.php on line 71
[28-Apr-2016 16:56:47 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: db in /home/joeynlxj/public_html/fnb/pages/forgotpass.php on line 11
[28-Apr-2016 16:56:47 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/joeynlxj/public_html/fnb/pages/forgotpass.php on line 11
```

My database works just fine, it's used through another file.

Comment: Anything in the error logs?

Comment: Backticks (`) are used for indicating _field names_ in MySQL (see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11321508/2137833). Is the query being executed at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: I added those backticks later on to see if it would help, so that's not the problem, the query is not being executed at all. but when I remove the `$updateStmt` lines the code works just fine, so i know the problem has to be somewhere in there.

Comment: this is the error log `[28-Apr-2016 16:56:47 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: loggedin in /home/joeynlxj/public_html/fnb/layout/header.php on line 71
[28-Apr-2016 16:56:47 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: db in /home/joeynlxj/public_html/fnb/pages/forgotpass.php on line 11
[28-Apr-2016 16:56:47 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/joeynlxj/public_html/fnb/pages/forgotpass.php on line 11`

Comment: `$db` isn't in your function scope

Comment: `$result .= "".$charArray[$randItem];` and why does your concatenation include an empty string? That's pretty pointless

Comment: doesn't a require carry through to functions?

Comment: @JoeyMariah - Nope, a require doesn't make anything magically global, otherwise you'd never need to pass arguments to any function, and every variable declared in your script would exist in every point of time and space at the same time, and unless you're from Gallifrey, you'd never be able to keep track of what was what without being driven insane by the gibbering horrors of 27-dimensional reality

Comment: oh okay, i think that might be the problem then... I'll try it out..

Comment: IT WORKS!!! Thank you guys so much! I've been struggling with this for hours now

Answer (score 1):

Reconnect to the database from within the function.

in my case, all I had to do was add `require('../fnb/core/database.php')` to my code.

Comment: I always admired someone who could fix things, and on their own ;-)